# "Será que ela não vai achar caro?" ou "Será que ela vai achar caro?"

Tags: ambiguidades, semântica

Existe alguma diferença semântica entre as duas frases?   Quando usar uma ou outra?

> Contexto:
>
> **a) "Vai custar quinze mil Euros."**
>
> **b) "Será que ela vai achar caro?" / "Será que ela não vai achar caro?"**

Como até o momento ninguém aventurou uma resposta, acrescento mais dois exemplos:

> **a) "vamos fazer tudo escondido dele."**
>
> **b) "será que ele não vai ficar zangado?"**

e

> **a) "eu nem me despedi dos teus pais. Será que eles vão ficar zangados?"**

Comment: Não quererás dizer «não será que ela vai achar caro?»? «Será que ela não vai achar caro?» parece-me uma construção estranha. «Será que ela não vem?» faz sentido e é claramente diferente de «Será que ela vem (mesmo)?». Mas alguém interrogar-se se alguém deixa de achar qualquer coisa...

Comment: @Artefacto "Será que ela não vai contar pra todo o mundo?", "Será que ele não vai ficar com raiva?"  is current usage in Brazilian Portuguese.   "Não será que....?" isn't.

Comment: Para mim, «Será que ele não vai ficar com raiva?» é igualmente estranho. Repara que em «Será que ela não vem?», existe uma presunção de que ela vem e estamos a interrogarmo-nos se afinal isso não é verdade. Para a tua frase ser equivalente tínhamos de admitir que havia uma presunção de ela ia ficar com raiva. Com «não», só consigo pensar em «Não será que ela vai ficar com raiva?», que mesmo assim é um pouco estranho. Melhor: «não irá ela ficar com raiva?», «não ficará (ela) com raiva?».

Comment: Já agora, a diferença entre «irá ela ficar raiva?» e «não irá ela ficar com raiva?» é que no segundo caso estamos a sugerir como mais provável que ela vai de facto ficar com raiva (ou simplesmente o receamos), enquanto a primeira pergunta é mais neutra.

Comment: @Artefacto   contexto:  a)- Vamos fazer escondido. Depois a gente conta pra ele.   b)- Será que ele não vai ficar com raiva?    c)-  Ligue o carro e vamos embora.  Ele que pegue um taxi se quiser.   d)- Será que ele não vai achar (que é) uma tremenda falta de consideração?  Acho melhor esperar.

Comment: @Artefacto Eu acho a versão do Centaurus mais natural: *será que ela não vai achar caro*. Mas vejo a mesma diferença que tu entre *irá ela...* e *não irá ela...*

Comment: Penso q você quer: 'Será que ela vai o achar caro?' e 'Será que ela não vai o achar caro?'

Comment: @robertotomás  Não, não é isso.  Seria nos mesmos moldes de: "será que ele vai ficar zangado se nós fizermos isso?" x "será que ele não vai ficar zangado se nós fizermos isso".   Há uma difeença sutil entre as duas e que eu acho difícil explicar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certas ambas estão, e a resposta anterior já dizia isso, asserção com a qual eu concordo plenamente!!

Quanto à semântica, arrisco-me a propor uma resposta diferente: depende!

Em alguns contextos, como os exemplificados, este "não" combinado com o "será" parece dar um sentido de expectativa presumida. Quando usamos a interjeição "será" de forma interrogativa, estamos muito frequentemente lançando uma dúvida. Ex:

> - O João vai passar de ano!
> - Será?

E quando dizemos "será que ...?", normalmente estamos lançando uma dúvida sobre a asserção que procede o "será que".

Então, com base nisso, eu concluo que a pessoa que fala:

> Mas será que ela não vai ficar brava?

Ela lança a dúvida sobre a hipótese de ela NÃO ficar brava, ou seja, ela acredita que a pessoa FICARÁ brava, mas tem dúvidas.

Já quando a pessoa fala:

> Mas será que ela vai ficar brava?

Ela lança a dúvida sobre a hipótese de ela FICAR brava, ou seja, ela também está em dúvida, mas acredita mais na hipótese de que a pessoa NÃO ficará brava.

Por estas razões, acredito que sim, hajam diferenças no sentido expressado.

Comment: Looking at some comments, I'm wondering whether I did it right or wrong by writing my answer in Portuguese. Should I edit it and translate to English? Is there any guideline about this?

Comment: Sê bem-vindo ao site. A resposta está muito bem em português: a regra é responder na língua da pergunta. Já agora, o que é que nos comentários te sugeriu que a resposta devesse ser escrita em inglês?

Answer (score 0):

Ambas estão correctas. É bastante semelhante a

> Importas-te de me passar o sal?
>
> Não te importas de me passar o sal?

O sentido da frase é o mesmo, e o seu significado é também igual. São casos irrelevantes que em português são intercambiáveis